# Flex Window always-on-top

Tags: windows, macos, apache-flex, air, always-on-top

I set `alwaysOnTop="true"` in `mx:WindowedApplication`tag. This does not work in OSX but works in Windows.

How can I solve this for OSX?

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this on Leopard, to keep a window in front of all other windows, in MXML (also works in actionscript) - do this:

```
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
    layout="absolute" width="1024" height="768"
    alwaysInFront="true">
```